# Python extract text files

Tags: python, file, search, text

1. I have several test files kept in one directory
2. I want to go to each file and search some text "Text 1" and "Text 2" and print everything in front of this text in output file....
3. This I have done using python script.....
4. But next thing is I want only the first instance of "Text 1" and "Text 2" in each file. If I add `break` in the current script I am not able to print in out file..

Please guide me.. I am a python beginner...

```
import os
path = "D:\test"
in_files = os.listdir(path)
desc = open("desc.txt", "w")
print >> desc, "Mol_ID,   Text1,  Text2"
moldesc = ['Text1', 'Text2']
for f in in_files:
    file = os.path.join(path, f)
    text = open(file, "r")
    hit_count = 0
    hit_count1 = 0
    for line in text:
        if moldesc[0] in line:
            Text1 = line.split()[-1]
        if moldesc[1] in line:
            Text2 = line.split()[-1]
            print >> desc, f + "," + Text1 + "," + Text2
text.close()
print "Text extraction done !!!"
```

Comment: due you want first instance of both or just one of them?

Comment: i have difficulties understandind your problem. could you please provide a sample input and the output you would like to have?

Comment: why not use find, xargs, grep and sed ?

Comment: @njzk2 i am not using grep or other similar commands since i want to do more stuff on top of it....

Comment: Problem solved !!! simply closing the out file solved the problem....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

- Your `text.close()` should be at the same level as the `for line in text` loop.
- The `print >> desc` statement is out of place: you should print only if both `Text1` and `Text2` are defined. You could set them as None just outside the `for line in text` loop, and test if they are both not `None`. (Alternatively, you could set `hit_count0=1` in the `if moldesc[0]` test, `hit_count1=1` in the `if moldesc[1]` and test for `hit_count0 and hit_count1`). In that case, print the output and use a `break` to escape the loop.

(so, in plain code:)

```
for f in in_files:
    file = os.path.join(path, f)
    with open(file, "r") as text:
        hit_count = 0
        hit_count1 = 0
        for line in text:
            if moldesc[0] in line:
                Text1 = line.split()[-1]
                hit_count = 1
            if moldesc[1] in line:
                Text2 = line.split()[-1]
                hit_count1 = 1
            if hit_count and hit_count1:
                print >> desc, f + "," + Text1 + "," + Text2
                break
```

There's a third issue:

You mention wanting the text **before** `Text1` ? Then you may want to use `Text1 = line[:line.index(moldesc[0])]` instead of your `Text1 = line.split()[-1]`...

Answer (score 0):

I would go for an `mmap` and possibly use CSV for the results file approach, something like (untested) and rough around the edges... (needs better error handling, may want to use mm.find() instead of an regex, some of the code is copied verbatim from OP etc..., and my computer's battery is about to die...)

```
import os 
import csv
import mmap
from collections import defaultdict

PATH = r"D:\test"  # note 'r' prefix to escape '\t' interpretation
in_files = os.listdir(path)

fout = open('desc.txt', 'w')
csvout = csv.writer(fout)
csvout.writerow( ['Mol_ID', 'Text1', 'Text2'] )

dd = defaultdict(list)

for filename in in_files: 
    fin = open(os.path.join(path, f))
    mm = mmap.mmap(fin.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    # Find stuff
    matches = re.findall(r'(.*?)(Text[12])', mm) # maybe user finditer depending on exact needs
    for text, matched in matches:
        dd[matched].append(text)
    # do something with dd - write output using csvout.writerow()...
    mm.close()
    fin.close()
csvout.close()
```